# merge directed acyclic graphs minimize the number of final graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, merge

I have some directed acyclic graphs with same nodes. I want to merge this graphs. Merge here means combine the edges of two graph. If the merged graph have no cycle, then the two graph could merge to one. Given n graph, I would like to find the minimal number of merged graph. It seems like NP-Hard problem. Is there any related work in graph?Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a case for which a simple greedy algorithm can't be applied? I mean, when you take the first graph and try to merge it with all other graphs sequentially, then take the first of the remaining graphs and so on.

Comment: Minimal number of merged graphs or maximal number?